# Javascript - Make a local variable act like a global

Tags: javascript, error-handling, global-variables, local-variables

I'm learning about local and global variables. In this program, my function does 2 things.  If you enter a number greater than 0 into the function, it `sets` the Y variable.  If you pass a 0, it `displays` the Y variable.

```js
function sety(x) {
  if (x>0)  y=x;  else alert(y);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sety(222)">SET Y to 222</button>
<button onclick="sety(333)">SET Y to 333</button>
<button onclick="sety(0)">display the Y variable</button>
```

In this example, Y is a global variable.  What if I wanted to create a program that contained no global variables?  If I put `var y` in the function, that makes it local, right?, but it doesn't work.

I also have a second question.  If I were to click the Display button before setting the variable, I would get an error.  I tried adding `if(x=="undefined")` but that still gave me an error.  How can I prevent an error in that situation.

Comment: For the second question, you must define a variable before you try to use it. `y` isn't defined until the first `y = x` call, which doesn't happen if you click the "get" button first.

Answer (score 3):

Create a closure.

```
(function() {
    var y; // y is now local to this closure
    window.sety = function(x) {
        // however you still want sety() to be a global function,
        // so you have to do this explicitly
        if( x > 0) y = x;
        else alert(y);
    };
})();
```

I will note that having a function do two things is generally a bad idea - especially with a name like "set y". Consider separating that out into two functions, `sety(x)` and `gety()`, with the latter *returning* the value instead of just alerting it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a property to the function and update it.

```js
function sety(x) {
    if (x > 0) {
        sety.y = x;
    } else {
        alert(sety.y);
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sety(222)">SET Y to 222</button>
<button onclick="sety(333)">SET Y to 333</button>
<button onclick="sety(0)">display the Y variable</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it says that y is undefined if you try to display the variable without settings it is because the line `y = x` acts like `var y = x` which defines the variable y. If that line had not executed before you tried to display it (which it wouldn't if you attempted to display it first), then `var y` would never have happened, which gives you an error. To fix that, you must define y before the else.

The snippet below will be a "local variable". In essence, it just redefines y every time the function is executed.

```js
function sety(x) {
  var y;
  if (x > 0) y = x;
  else alert(y);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sety(222)">SET Y to 222</button>
<button onclick="sety(333)">SET Y to 333</button>
<button onclick="sety(0)">display the Y variable</button>
```

The snippet below will only define y if it is already not defined.

```js
function sety(x) {
  if (x > 0) y = x;
  else {
    if (typeof y == 'undefined') {
      var y;
    }
    alert(y);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sety(222)">SET Y to 222</button>
<button onclick="sety(333)">SET Y to 333</button>
<button onclick="sety(0)">display the Y variable</button>
```

Now I wouldn't suggest using the code you used. The snippet below is the code you should use.

```js
function sety(x) {
  y = x;
}

function gety() {
  if (typeof y == 'undefined') {
    y = 'undefined';
  }
  alert(y);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sety(222)">SET Y to 222</button>
<button onclick="sety(333)">SET Y to 333</button>
<button onclick="gety()">display the Y variable</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access that variable as follow: `window.y` because you're setting implicitly to the `window` object when you're doing this `y = x`.

*This is to overcome the undefined variable problem*

```js
function sety(x) {
  if (x > 0) y = x;
  else alert(window.y);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sety(222)">SET Y to 222</button>
<button onclick="sety(333)">SET Y to 333</button>
<button onclick="sety(0)">display the Y variable</button>
```

Comment: OP said. _In this example, Y is a global variable. What if I wanted to create a program that contained **no global variables**_

Comment: @MaheerAli yes, but this is a way to overcome the undefined variable problem the OP is facing.